# Converting flutter adMob functionality from provider to riverpods

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, provider

I'm migrating my whole app to riverpods and encountered one lasting error. Essentially, in my main.dart I used to have Provider.value such that:

```
final adState = AdState(initialization: adsInitialization);

runApp(
  Provider.value(
    value: adState,
    child: MyApp(email, password, language),
  ),
);
```

'''

And now I have

```
 runApp(ProviderScope(
  child: MyApp(email, password, language),
));
```

As specified in the riverpods docs. I was wondering what needs to be modified to pass the adstate 'value' like before? I'm a bit confused of what the Provider.value even did in the first place...

Here's the error I get

```
flutter: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<UserSettings> above this HomePage Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that HomePage is under your MultiProvider/Provider<UserSettings>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
```

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is enough context to fully answer your question. Based on what I can tell, you're still using Provider to get access to `UserSettings` but there isn't an instance of `Provider<UserSettings>` in your tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Riverpod equivalent of `Provider<AdState>.value(value: adState)` would be `Provider<AdState>((ref) => adState)`. However, I would initialize the instance inside of the provider as such.

```dart
final adState = Provider<AdState>((ref) {
  return AdState(initialization: adsInitialization);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question given I attempted to do the same.

This is my approach using riverpod.

So, with riverpod you can actually create your own ProviderContainer prior to runApp(...)

```
  final container = ProviderContainer();

  // now you have access to container.read to perform any provider initializations prior to runApp.
  container.read(adStateProvider);

  // Use UncontrolledProviderScope instead of ProviderScope
  // and pass in the container.
  runApp(
    UncontrolledProviderScope(
      container: container,
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
```